# Trying to make an onclick button but it keeps saying showTest is undefined

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import reactDom from 'react-dom';
        
class Second extends React.Component { 
    showText= alert ("Got it");
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick ={ showText }> Click Me  </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Second;
```

I am trying to make an onclick  button but it keeps saying showTest is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the this keyword as you are refering to an object of the class.

```
onClick ={ this.showText }>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

class Second extends React.Component { 
  showText = () => alert ("Got it");
  
  render () {
    return (
        <div>
          <button onClick ={this.showText}> Click Me  </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Second;
```